# What is the algebraic closure of the field of rational functions over $\mathbb{C}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

**Main Question**

I was searching for a calculable working example of
algebraically closed field of characteristic $0$,
other than $\mathbb{C}$ or $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$.
Then I came across the following question:
What is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{C}(x)$?

---

**Basics: Field of Fractions, Rational Functions**

Given an integral domain $R$, let $R^* = R - \{0\}$ be the set of nonzero elements.
Define an equivalence relation $\sim$ on $R \times R^*$
by letting $(n,d) \sim (m,c)$ to denote $nc = md$.
Define $\dfrac{n}{d}$ denote $(n,d)$.
Then $\mathrm{Frac}(R) = (R\times R^*)/\sim$ has the structure of field and called the field of fraction of $R$.

Given a field $\mathbb{K}$, let $\mathbb{K}[x]$ denote the polynomial ring in one indeterminate. Then $\mathbb{K}[x]$ is an integral domain,
so we can consider the field of fraction.
Let $\mathbb{K}(x)$ denote $\mathrm{Frac}(\mathbb{K}[x])$
and is called the field of rational functions.

---

**Not Algebraically Closed**

Let $\mathbb{F}$ be the field of rational functions over complex numbers:
$\mathbb{F} = \mathbb{C}(x)$.
Is it algebraically closed? No, it isn't.
Let $p(x) \in \mathbb{Q}[x] \subset \mathbb{F}$ be a polynomial over rational number.
For example, let $T^2 - p(x) \in \mathbb{F}[T]$ be a polynomial over $\mathbb{F}$.
Consider the solution for $T$ of $T^2 - p(x) = 0$.
Then we obtain $T = \pm\sqrt{p(x)}$, but $\pm\sqrt{p(x)}\notin\mathbb{F}$.
So $\mathbb{F}$ is not algebraically closed.
Then my question is:
What is the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}$?
Let $\overline{\mathbb{F}}$ be the algebraic closure of $\mathbb{F}$.

---

**Examples of Fields of Characteristic Zero**

The algebraic closure of $\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathbb{C}$,
both uncountable cardinality.

The algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$ is
the field of algebraic numbers $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$,
both countable cardinality.

There are many countable algebraically closed field
between $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$ and $\mathbb{C}$,
for example, $\overline{\mathbb{Q}(\pi)}$

$\overline{\mathbb{F}} = \overline{\mathbb{C}(x)}$
is equal to $\overline{\mathbb{R}(x)}$.

---

**Characterize Elements of $\mathbb{F}$**

The question what is $\mathbb{F}$ can be translated to
how to characterize each element of $\mathbb{F}$.
In the case of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}=\mathbb{C}$,
we can characterize an element of $r\in\mathbb{R}$ by
a convergent series of elements of $\mathbb{Q}$, and then
we can characterize an element of $c\in\mathbb{C}$
by a pair of elements of $\mathbb{R}$.
How about $\mathbb{F}$?
In order to use the same convergent series strategy,
we need to define distance between rational functions,
but I don't know it well.

---

**Algebraic Function [PEND: ToDo]**

Although a rational function $r(x)\in\mathbb{F}$
can be considered a complex function,
the definition does not restrict
what the domain indeterminate $x$ resides.
Moreover, $f\in\overline{\mathbb{F}}$ may have branches,
for example, $x^2 + T^2 = 1$ imply $T$ is a two valued function.

---

**At last, the Question is:**

What is the set $\overline{\mathbb{C}(x)}$
the algebraic closure of the field $\mathbb{C}(x)$?

Any ideas?

Comment: exp is holomorphic but not algebraic.

Comment: $\overline {\Bbb Q}$ is not $\Bbb C$. Also, the two square roots of $x$ are in $\Bbb F$, but aren't holomorphic. They aren't even functions, really.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_function

Comment: Oh, I made much mistakes... May I rewrite the article? @Arthur

Comment: I think rewriting to correct these mistakes sounds like a good idea.

Comment: Rewriting is done, with a bit of pending. Thank you.

Comment: "The key result is that the Puiseux series form an algebraically closed field. Hence the set of Puiseux series algebraic over $\Bbb C(x)$  gives an algebraic closure $\overline{\Bbb C}(x)$ of $\mathbb{C} (x)$".